# Unity - How to go to the previous scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I’m making a game and I made a Store in it, and I need a script to put in a button in the store scene, that go to the previous loaded scene. For example, I completed the level one and now I’m in the level selection menu, I want to go to the store so I click in “store” button. Now, in the store, I want to go back, so I click in the “back” button and instead of going back to the level selection menu, I go to the start menu, so I need a script to put on the “back” button that brings me to the previous loaded scene. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

put this in any class

```
static List<string> sceneList = new List<string>();
```

when you load a new scene , right before you call sceneManager

```
<classyouputscenelistin>.sceneList.Add("<scenename>");
```

when you go back

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(<classyouputscenelistin>.sceneList[<classyouputscenelistin.sceneList.Count -2], LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

replace  to the class name you added scene list to

replace  with the name of the scene you are loading

edit: go back to scene before last

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(<classyouputscenelistin>.sceneList[<classyouputscenelistin.sceneList.Count -3], LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

Basically Count - 2 is previous scene anything before that (-3, -4) load the scenes before it, if you don't want a scene to be tracked in this list don't do this:

```
<classyouputscenelistin>.sceneList.Add("<scenename>");
```

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly you would just omit this <classyouputscenelistin>.sceneList.Add("<scenename>"); when going to the store to go back to the previous scene aside from store

Comment: Count -2 goes to the last, if you want the one before that do Count -3

Comment: I edited answer again, at this point try to wrap your head around the code and make it your own, basically you are tracking every scene you have been to in a string array and then taking the item before the last to go back